# Laravel RateLimiter

Tags: laravel, race-condition, rate-limiting

I'm fairly new to Laravel and am currently using an API that has a limit of 25 requests per minute.
I have a controller method `sendRequest()` which is used by all methods to send requests to the API so I was thinking this is the place to put a rate limiter that checks if the current request can be added to the queue if the limit is not yet reached.

I was thinking something like this:

```
protected function sendRequest(){
    if ($this->allowRequest()) {
        //proceed to api call
    }
}

protected function allowRequest() {
    $allow = false;
    //probably a do-while loop to check if the limit has been reached within the timeframe?
}
```

I've found this class `Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter` that I think could be useful but have no idea how to use it yet. Can anyone point me to the right direct with this? So basically the request should "wait" and execute only if the 25 requests/minute limit hasn't been reached.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter` class has `hit` and `tooManyAttempts` methods you can use like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

protected function sendRequest()
{
    if ($this->hasTooManyRequests()) {
        // wait
        sleep(
            $this->limiter()
                ->availableIn($this->throttleKey()) + 1 // <= optional plus 1 sec to be on safe side
        );

        // Call this function again.
        return $this->sendRequest();
    }
    
    //proceed to api call
    $response = apiCall();

    // Increment the attempts
    $this->limiter()->hit(
        $this->throttleKey(), 60 // <= 60 seconds
    );

    return $response;
}

/**
 * Determine if we made too many requests.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function hasTooManyRequests()
{
    return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
        $this->throttleKey(), 25 // <= max attempts per minute
    );
}

/**
 * Get the rate limiter instance.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter
 */
protected function limiter()
{
    return app(RateLimiter::class);
}

/**
 * Get the throttle key for the given request.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function throttleKey()
{
    return 'custom_api_request';
}
```

See [`Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php) class for more available methods.

You may also check [`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins`](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/master/auth-backend/ThrottlesLogins.php) as an example to figure out how to use `Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter` class.

**Note**: The `RateLimiter` methods use seconds instead of minutes since Laravel >= 5.8 and got a [major improvement](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32726) on v8.x.

Comment: don't you think that`ThrottlesLogins` won't  work in this case, because the api request could be either `get`, `post` anything. `ThrottlesLogins` is specifically to login only.

Comment: This is not `ThrottlesLogins`, I said you can check that to figure out how you can use `RateLimitter`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the class, but what if the api call is inside a cron job that loops send requests to more than the api limit? It should be able to wait and continue execution on its own without user interaction.

Comment: @Jenny then you can use `sleep` to wait, I updated my answer.

Comment: It worked! Just a correction though, the hit() method accepts a time delay in minutes, so it should be 1 instead of 60. Was wondering why the attempts were not resetting :P

Comment: When the limit is reached it waits using the sleep function but after waiting it enters the `$this->hasTooManyRequests()` condition again with a -1 value on `availableIn()` so it throws an error that sleep function cannot accept a negative value. Any idea what my cause this? I've fixed it by updating the condition to:
`if ($this->hasTooManyRequests() && $this->limiter()->availableIn($this->throttleKey()) > -1){` probably not the best solution but this is the only way I can get it to work.

Comment: @Jenny on Laravel >= 5.8 the `hit()` method accepts seconds not minutes check it here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php#L87

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much, I made some edits.

Answer (score 1):

Here you'll need the shared timer like control for frequency capping of the outgoing request. Create a class that will be a singleton for Laravel application and can be shared within requests.

```php
class FrequencyCapper{
    protected $start, $call, $request_frequency, $limit_interval;
    
    public function __construct($frequency, $interval_in_minute){
        $this->start = time();
        $this->call = 0;
        $this->request_frequency = frequency; // frequency of call
        $this->limit_interval = $interval_in_minute; // in minutes
    } 

    protected function allowRequest(){
        $diff = time() - $this->start;
        if($diff >= 60 * $this->limit_interval){
            $this->start = time();
            $this->call = 0;
        }
    
        return $diff <  60 * $this->limit_interval && $this->call < $this->request_frequency){
            $this->call++;
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, attach this class as a singleton in laravel service container. bind singleton in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`'s boot method.

```php
$this->app->singleton('FrequencyCapper', function ($app) {
     return new FrequencyCapper(25, 1); //max 25 request per minute
});
```

Now, this class will be available to all controllers as a dependency. You can inject `FrequencyCapper` dependency to any controller method as given,

```php
class MyController extends Controller{
 
    protected function sendRequest(FrequencyCapper $capper){
        if($capper->allowRequest()){
            //you can call the api
        }
    }
}
```

if you want, you can use `microtime()` instead time() in `FrequencyCapper` class. If you want to throttle the incoming request to your own api, you can use laravel's `throttle` middleware as,

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'throttle:25,1'], function(){
    //define your routes here
});
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants, the `throttle` middleware limits each authenticated user to access a route more than 25 request/minute.

Comment: have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#rate-limiting when you are not using the `auth:api`, the `throttle` middleware works as a simple request rate limiter. Isn't it true?

Comment: no the key of `throttle` middleware is `user`+`ip` for authenticated users and `ip` for guest users. you can check it here: `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests`

Comment: It's Number of request, per minute. If we want to set  40 request per 2 minute, it should be as `throttle:40,2` check      * @param  int|string  $maxAttempts
     * @param  float|int  $decayMinutes parameter in  here https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php

Comment: I know, but the OP has a function (`sendRequest`) that calls an API, they want to limit this function to 25 calls per minute. It has nothing to do with throttling a route!

Comment: Anyways, you can use throttle to rate limit, depends upon the ay you choose. however, laravel is a rich framework and has many ways to achieve same things. However, you said `throttle` middleware is `user,ip` can you explain this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216894/discussion-between-hafez-divandari-and-kiran-maniya).

Comment: Thank you Kiran for the FrequencyCapper class. But the current number of requests should be persistent across different sessions since users and cron jobs are using the the sendRequest method. This could be achieved by using the RateLimiter class I believe, otherwise I can use server cache or database to save the current number of calls. Most importantly the call should be able to wait  for others to complete and execute on its own when the limit is no longer reached.

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 8 and PHP 7.4 I take the example of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62642143/3145399

and make this Trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter;

trait CustomRateLimiter {

    protected string $throttleKey = 'GeneralRateLimit';

    /**
     * Determine if we made too many requests.
     *
     * @param int $maxAttempts
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function hasTooManyRequests( $maxAttempts = 10 ): bool {
        return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
            $this->throttleKey(), $maxAttempts // <= max attempts per minute
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the rate limiter instance.
     *
     * @return RateLimiter
     */
    protected function limiter(): RateLimiter {
        return app( RateLimiter::class );
    }

    /**
     * Get the throttle key for the given request.
     *
     * @param string $key
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function throttleKey( $key = 'GeneralRateLimit' ): string {
        return $this->throttleKey ?? $key;
    }

    /**
     * @param Closure $callback Anonymous function to be executed - example: function(){ return realFunction();}
     * @param int $maxAttempts Maximum number of hits before process sleeps
     * @param string $throttleKey If you have different Apis, change this key to a single key.
     * @param int $decaySeconds Time that will sleep when the condition of $maxAttempts is fulfilled
     * @param int $optionalSecond Optional plus secs to be on safe side
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function sendRequest( Closure $callback, $maxAttempts = 10, $throttleKey = 'GeneralRateLimit', $decaySeconds = 1, $optionalSecond = 1 ) {
        $this->throttleKey = $throttleKey;

        if ( $this->hasTooManyRequests( $maxAttempts ) ) {
            // wait
            sleep( $this->limiter()->availableIn( $this->throttleKey() ) + $optionalSecond );

            // Call this function again.
            return $this->sendRequest( $callback, $maxAttempts, $throttleKey, $decaySeconds, $optionalSecond );
        }

        //proceed to api call
        $response = $callback();

        // Increment the attempts
        $this->limiter()->hit(
            $this->throttleKey(), $decaySeconds // <= 1 seconds
        );

        return $response;
    }

}
```

how to use it?

```
use App\Traits\CustomRateLimiter;
class MyClass {
    use CustomRateLimiter;
    public function realApiToCall($var1){
     // custom logic
    }

    public function apiCall($var1){
     $apiResponse = $this->sendRequest( function () use ( $var1 ) {
            return $this->realApiToCall($var1);
        }, 4, 'customKey1', 1 );
    }
}
```