# How can I show custom message to users when a particular route is hit more than specified counts per minute in laravel8 Routeserviceprovider?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, rate-limiting

How can I show custom message to users when a particular route is hit more than specified counts per minute in laravel8 Routeserviceprovider?

```
RateLimiter::for('customRateLimiter', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(2)->by($request->ip());
        });
```

Currently, if the no of hits cross the hits/minute specified in routeserviceprovider.php, then a universal page appears saying 429 (Too many Requests).

But instead what I want is that, if ratelimit count exceeds, then I have to show the users a error/warning flash message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on RateLimiting in Laravel.
The RateLimiter class has a tooManyAttempts method.

So you could do something like below:

```
  if (RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts()) {
     return back()->with(['message' => 'Your message']);
  } else {
     // proceed
  }
```

Keep in mind I'm no expert look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62642143/9636400) SO answer or check the class for more information [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php).